# QVTKOpenGLWidget doesn't respond to signal, while other widgets in the same .ui do respond to it

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, vtk

I am trying to draw a cylinder in a QVTKOpenGLWidget. I use Qt Creator, with qt version 5.12.0 (msvc2017_64). The QVTKOpenGLWidget is promoted from QWidget, and I use QVTKOpenGLWidget.h in the VTK include folder.

When I create cylinder, renderer, vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow etc in constructor like most of examples available, nothing goes wrong, the cylinder is shown in the QVTKOpenGLWidget. The code is like below:

```
mainui::mainui(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::mainui)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto cylinderSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCylinderSource>::New();
    cylinderSource->SetCenter(0, 0, 0);
    cylinderSource->SetRadius(5.0);
    cylinderSource->SetHeight(7.0);
    cylinderSource->SetResolution(100);

    auto mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(cylinderSource->GetOutputPort());

    auto actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);

    auto renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    renderer->AddActor(actor);

    auto win = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow>::New();
    win->AddRenderer(renderer);
    ui->display3d->SetRenderWindow(win);
}
```

In this condition, the result is like below: 
[image]

However when I add an action with function "triggered()" as a signal, add VTK-related code in a function and add that function as a slot function, and connect them, the QVTKOpenGLWidget seems not working (totally black, no cylinder). But other widgets seems working well. The code is like below:

```
void mainui::paint() {
    ui->textEdit->append("Hello vtk!");

    auto cylinderSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCylinderSource>::New();
    cylinderSource->SetCenter(0, 0, 0);
    cylinderSource->SetRadius(5.0);
    cylinderSource->SetHeight(7.0);
    cylinderSource->SetResolution(100);

    auto mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(cylinderSource->GetOutputPort());

    auto actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);

    auto renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    renderer->AddActor(actor);

    auto win = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow>::New();
    win->AddRenderer(renderer);
    ui->display3d->SetRenderWindow(win);

    ui->textEdit->append("textEdit respond to trigger signal");
}
```

The constructor:

```
mainui::mainui(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::mainui)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

The connector:
[image]

And run result:
[image]

Comment: I've tryied the parts of code that you provide in my own project and cannot reproduce your problem, I get the desired behaviour (the cilinder apears when the `action_open` is triggered). Can you provide a complete example where the error happens so we can reproduce it?

Comment: Hi, the project is in: https://github.com/pkusunjy/PPS

Comment: Do not name the slot paint. You will hide the original paint function of QWidget.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that your cylinder is drawn when you interact with the `QVTKOpenGLWidget` (after `action_open` is triggered, you move the 3D display and the cylinder will appear). This is because the `QVTKOpenGLWidget` is not updated when you create your renderers, windows and so on. So you need to add `ui->display3d->update();` before exiting `void mainui::paint()` function to force an update on the `display3d` widget:

```
void mainui::paint()
{
  ui->textEdit->append("Nope");

  auto cylinderSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCylinderSource>::New();
  cylinderSource->SetCenter(0, 0, 0);
  cylinderSource->SetRadius(5.0);
  cylinderSource->SetHeight(7.0);
  cylinderSource->SetResolution(100);

  auto mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
  mapper->SetInputConnection(cylinderSource->GetOutputPort());

  auto actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
  actor->SetMapper(mapper);

  auto renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
  renderer->AddActor(actor);

  auto win = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow>::New();
  win->AddRenderer(renderer);

  ui->display3d->SetRenderWindow(win);
  ui->display3d->update();//This is the new line
}
```

You do not need to manually call [`QWidget::update()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) manully when you create your cylinder in the constructor because the widget is drawn after the constructor.

Here you can see it working:

[image]

**Note**: I learned this in the pcl tutorial: [Create a PCL visualizer in Qt with cmake](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/qt_visualizer.php).

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. However I move my mouse, click or wheel, the cylinder doesn't appear. Even I add the new line in the slot function, it still doesn't work.